# how to get if array key is protected?

Tags: php, arrays, protected

i have this type of array:-
i want to get array elemtn.

```
context_course Object
 (
                     [_id:protected] => 15
                     [_contextlevel:protected] => 50
                     [_instanceid:protected] => 2 
                     [_path:protected] => /1/3/15 [_depth:protected] => 3 
)
```

the problem is `[_id:protected]`
i want to there value `15`
how can i get if element is `protected`.
thanks.

Comment: inherit that class with a new class and there you will have an access to the protected property of the class

Answer (score 5):

If a property is protected, it means the developer of the class doesn't want you to be able to freely directly access or modify its value from the public context.

If you analyze the class definition for this object, you will most likely find a method that will give you access to the value, for example it could be:

```
$obj->getId();
```

More info: [Property Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: What if key has a dollar sign? How do I access then....Obviously `$obj->get{'$t'}();` has failed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an array, it is an object.

You will need to implement a public `accessor`, also known as a `getter` to access the object property.

```
class context_course 
{
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->_id;
  }
}
```