# Accessing object property returns property name with $

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am having trouble accessing the object property. It should be straightforward, but I am getting

> Notice : Undefined property: myClass::$myname:protected in ...

My object, when I do a `print_r` looks like this:

```
myClass Object
(
    [myname:protected] => Array
        (
            [key1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [slug] => name
                    [name] => Big Name
                )

  .
  .
  .
   [mykey] => stdClass Object
       (...
```

And I tried printing

```
print_r($this->{'myname:protected'});
```

to see if I'll get the array out, from which I can get what I need. But I got the above error.

`print_r($this);` returns my object, since I am inside a `public` function (method) in my class `myClass`.

Why can't I access that key, but when I do `print_r($this->mykey->property1)` for instance, I can easily get any property for `mykey` object?

Why is it adding `$` in front of the name? I know some oo php, but I'm still a beginner. I have a

```
protected $myname;
```

at the beginning of the file, and I'm using it in my `__construct()` like

```
public function __construct($myname){...}
```

*Note*: I am trying to modify and figure out someone else's code, so I'm not 100% sure what every single piece does yet :\

EDIT:

When I do

```
print_r($this->myname);
```

I get the array I need. Can anyone clarify why is that? Thanks.

Comment: `protected` is a form of private, so it can only be accessed from inside the class. If you want to get it from outside the class do something like `public function getMyname() { return $this->myname; }`

Comment: see this it may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082204/how-to-get-if-array-key-is-protected

Comment: visit here:http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: So in the end it's only because that variable is protected that I get that notice. The weird part was that I am inside the class (trying to print it out), so I thought that shouldn't matter.

Comment: You should acces it using `($this->{'myname'})` instead, the protected is not part of the identifier.

Comment: So `:protected` behind was just an identifier? Didn't know that. As I wrote, I got it to work by just printing `$this->myname`, but I was kinda surprised, since in my array I got it with that identifier. Guess there is a lot about oop php that I need to learn... Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Making up syntax, are we, eh?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ? Making up? I'm not sure what you mean :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member name is `myname` - the `:protected` shown in the output of print_r is just debugging information to show that its a protected member of the object.

So from a class method, you would access the member as:

```
$this->myname
```