# How to read array Result provided by google drive api

Tags: php, json

I am trying to read json provide by google drive api, but not able to read json.

i am trying to read modelData:protected data.

I got following result  under **$result**

```
[0] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile Object (
    [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
                [labels] => Array
                    (
                        [starred] => 
                        [hidden] => 
                        [trashed] => 
                        [restricted] => 
                        [viewed] => 
                    )

                [parents] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [kind] => drive#parentReference
                                [id] => 0B4tddddcc03RW42UTdjUlY3SDg
                                [selfLink] => 
                                [parentLink] =>
                                [isRoot] => 
                            )

                    )

         )



)
```

and i am trying to read parents[0]

And i write this code

```
foreach ($result as $res) {

print_r($res[modelData:protected]); 
}
```

This gives me error

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']' in**

Any idea? how to resolve this issue

Comment: Try `print_r($res["modelData:protected"]); `. It need the quotes in the array key.

Comment: @M4R1KU: i have modelData:protected and the solution provieded by you is not working..  blank screen

Comment: It seems to me that you can not get in the usual manner to that object is protected.

Comment: @Arun : i got only blank screen

Comment: @rad11: so any alternate solution for that?

Comment: put json please easy to find out.

Comment: @Irfan : i got array result

Comment: Try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082204/how-to-get-if-array-key-is-protected

Comment: are you using google php library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posted `$result` object seems to be a Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile Object which is belong to google PHP library.

The rule of **OOP visibility::protected** says that you cannot access that protected propery outside of class(learn more about OOP Visibility concept through googling it).

if you want list of all functions releted to class you can use php `get_class_methods()`

```
print_R(get_class_methods($result));
# it will all methods available to this class.
```

or you can search through a library codebase for desired method which fit's your requirement.

As per the coding standards used by the Libray  it's uses getters and setters for every **private or protected** property;

```
# for example if you want to access labels from above code then you can use 
$array = $result->getLabels();

# to get Parents
$parents = $result->getParents();

# if you want to set this properties you can use
$result->setLabels($array);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to read file using api